# Do 'verity' and 'verily' derive from 'very'?

Tags: meaning, etymology

The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/222821?rskey=MmmrZm&result=3#eid) (subscription required or a library card number in the UK) has the following entry for 'very' used as an adjective or an adverb :

> Forms:  α. Middle English (1500s Scottish) verray (Middle English verrai, verraie, 1500s ... (Show More)
> Frequency (in current use):  Show frequency band information
> Etymology: < Anglo-Norman verrai, verrey, verai, veray, Old French verai, varai, vrai... (Show More)

> I. That is in truth or reality, and related uses; true, faithful.
>
> 1. Really or truly entitled to the name or designation; possessing the true character of the person or thing named; properly so called or designated; = true adj. 7.

But I was unable to discover if the derivation of 'very' has roots which would link it to 'verily' and 'verity' both of which emphasise truth.

I wondered if 'very' means 'truly', in its original concept.

Comment: There is also the usage "The very thing." It still does mean "truly".

Comment: OED etymologies for *verily* and *verity* both mention *very.*

Comment: etymonline.com and the OED say *very*, *verity*, *verily* all come (by varying routes) from Latin *verus* meaning "true", so I'm not sure why you're asking this question. What isn't clear about the etymologies?

Comment: @StuartF Thank you for that information. Feel free to record it in an answer. Regards.

Comment: Here, required research would be looking up 'verily' in Etymon etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They share common etymology.

The etymology of "*very*" as [given on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/very)

> From Middle English verray, verrai (“true”), from Old French verai (“true”) (Modern French vrai), from assumed Vulgar Latin vērācus, alteration of Latin vērāx (“truthful”), from vērus (“true”), ultimately from Proto-Indo-European *weh₁- (“true, benevolent”).

See also [the Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/verily):

> verily (adv.)
>
> "in truth," early 14c., from Middle English verray "true, real" (see **very**) + **-ly** (2).

Comment: Given the etymology from "verax" and the related words "veritable", "verify" and so on  perhaps the more interesting question is when and how "very" came to mean "extreme" as well as "true".